# Cant run debugging in chrome, emulator, edge

Tags: android, flutter, dart, debugging, mobile

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
```

main.dart:1
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:5:1: Error: Expected an identifier, but got 'import'.
Try inserting an identifier before 'import'.
import 'dart:async';
^^^^^^

/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1:1: Error: Expected ';' after this.
s// Copyright 2014 The Flutter Authors. All rights reserved.
^

/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:5:1: Error: Directives must appear before any declarations.
Try moving the directive before any declarations.
import 'dart:async';
^^^^^^

/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:6:1: Error: Directives must appear before any declarations.
Try moving the directive before any declarations.

import 'dart:collection';
^^^^^^

/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:7:1: Error: Directives must appear before any declarations.
Try moving the directive before any declarations.
import 'dart:developer';

^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:9:1: Error: Directives must appear before any declarations.

Try moving the directive before any declarations.
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
foundation.dart:1
^^^^^^

/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:10:1: Error: Directives must appear before any declarations.
Try moving the directive before any declarations.
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
rendering.dart:1
^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:12:1: Error: Directives must appear before any declarations.

Try moving the directive before any declarations.
import 'binding.dart';

^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:13:1: Error: Directives must appear before any declarations.

Try moving the directive before any declarations.
import 'debug.dart';
^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:14:1: Error: Directives must appear before any declarations.
Try moving the directive before any declarations.
import 'focus_manager.dart';

^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:15:1: Error: Directives must appear before any declarations.
Try moving the directive before any declarations.
import 'inherited_model.dart';
^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:16:1: Error: Directives must appear before any declarations.
Try moving the directive before any declarations.
import 'notification_listener.dart';

^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:17:1: Error: Directives must appear before any declarations.
Try moving the directive before any declarations.
import 'widget_inspector.dart';
^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:19:1: Error: Directives must appear before any declarations.
Try moving the directive before any declarations.
export 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show
foundation.dart:1
^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:27:1: Error: Directives must appear before any declarations.
Try moving the directive before any declarations.

export 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show ErrorDescription, ErrorHint, ErrorSummary, FlutterError, debugPrint, debugPrintStack;
foundation.dart:1
^^^^^^

/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:28:1: Error: Directives must appear before any declarations.
Try moving the directive before any declarations.
export 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show ValueChanged, ValueGetter, ValueSetter, VoidCallback;
foundation.dart:1
^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:29:1: Error: Directives must appear before any declarations.

Try moving the directive before any declarations.
export 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show DiagnosticLevel, DiagnosticsNode;
foundation.dart:1
^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:30:1: Error: Directives must appear before any declarations.

Try moving the directive before any declarations.
export 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show Key, LocalKey, ValueKey;
foundation.dart:1

^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:31:1: Error: Directives must appear before any declarations.
Try moving the directive before any declarations.

export 'package:flutter/rendering.dart' show RenderBox, RenderObject, debugDumpLayerTree, debugDumpRenderTree;
rendering.dart:1
^^^^^^

/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1:1: Error: Type 's' not found.
s// Copyright 2014 The Flutter Authors. All rights reserved.
^

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1201
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

Comment: kindly provide your code also so that we can examine.

Comment: This seems just the whole error log. Please provide the things you tried to fix this issue, and having a relevant of your code would also help